# Dojo Widget: How to so set a url to a file inside the widget?

Tags: javascript, module, dojo, requirejs

I want to show a default image in my widget. What is the best solution to point to an image  which is located inside the widget folder structure?

require.toUrl("widgets.notes", "images/defaultAvatar.png"),

The output is:

htpp://www.example.com/widgets/main.notes 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `require.toUrl` is falsy, there are no second parameter taken.

Given that your modulepath to 'widgets' is set, instead do this:

```
    require.toUrl("widgets/notes/images/defaultAvatar.png")
```

If you send simply the package namespace (e.g. 'widget'), it will try to make use of the [CommonJS Package spec](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1). You will notice in one of the informations that the standard minimum requirement is:

- main - module that must be loaded when require(name) is called. Definition must be relative to the package description file.

Which is what `require.toUrl("widgets")` is interpreting.

One may however choose where the package 'root' should be looked for. So, if you have:

```
/
  dojo/
  dijit/
  dojox/
  widgets/
```

Then youre set from start with no interaction, 'widgets' is a global namespace pr definition. If it is not 'in-place' this is where `dojo.registerModulePath` (DEPRECATED as pr 1.7) comes in handy, see [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/registerModulePath.html)

If you have it set for another path (xdomain becomes really complicated however an absolute path is accepted) then you would do one of the two options here:

First an example layout of packages:

```
/ (webroot)
/dojo/
   dojo-release-x.y/
     dojo/
     dijit/
     dojox/
/widgets/
```

Option one is dojoConfig, set as `window.dojoConfig` prior to loading dojo.js script tag

```
var dojoConfig = {
  packages: [
    {
      name: "widgets",
      location: "/widgets"  // note, 'http://mydomain.tld/widget' would work
    }
  ]
};
```

Option two is as an additional, first parameter to `require`, like so:

```
require({
  packages: [
    {
      name: "widgets",
      location: "/widgets"
    }
  ]
}, ["widgets/notes"], function(Notes) {
 ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.

I want to link to an image inside my widget. If the user will put the widget into a folder named "module" the solution won't work.
How can i prevent this?

Comment: you cannot 'mess' with the structure in a package definition. For example in Java there is a class named: sun.security.jgss. If you were to move it, it would be equivalent to wanting to call it microsoft.security.jgss - seems a bit far fetched huh? :). What the user _can set is where the 'includepath' of a package is, i've ammended to the answer. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/registerModulePath.html

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out it worked for me

avatar: require.toUrl("widgets/MyFirstWidget/widget/images/edwin.jpg")

In the brackets start with the word widgets then forward slash followed by the complete url to the resource. Take for instance the example above, MyFirstWidget is the name of the widget and images is a folder i created inside widget to store image files